# android list view constant scroll amount

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I working on android app for TV platform where I have a list view with elements.
I have setup elements in the list view so there are always visble for example 5 of them, and half of the 6th element.

When I move across the list with remote controller, I want when list view needs to be scroll to show entire 6 element, not to scroll just enough to show the 6th element, but to scroll for a element height to again show half of the 7th element.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to achive.

How to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Just to make it a little bit clealer:

---

### Element 1

### Element 2

### Element 3

### Element 4

### Element 5

### Half of Element 6

This ok. Now with remote controller move focus down. This is what happens.

---

### Half of Element 1

### Element 2

### Element 3

### Element 4

### Element 5

### Element 6

A and I need this:

---

### Element 2

### Element 3

### Element 4

### Element 5

### Element 6

### Half of element 7

How to make list view whenever needs to scroll, scroll for exact amount of pixels as elements height?

Comment: You want after scrolling the list view remain elements have to  show right

Comment: I have added a example of my usecase.

Comment: you can use `requestChildRectangleOnScreen` , you need check `onKeyUp` then get `firstVisibleItem` then use `requestChildRectangleOnScreen`. but for last item i think this scenario has a problem

Comment: could you provide some code example? For the last element I already added one fake invisible item at the end, so the real last element is the same as others.

Comment: all method that i mentioned for you was brought from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html, see that

Comment: There are lack of examples how to use that method. I will take a look on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listview;
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                //Your code...
            }
        });
```

Comment: This will cause listview to jitter. If i always scroll manually a little bit. Im looking for general solution.